# How to set initially selected tab ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to set my Tab2 as the initially selected tab using ActionBarShelock but I'm having trouble getting to work.

The tabs are working perfectly but I can't get it to select the 2nd tab instead of the first one when the app starts.
Here's my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.AppThemeLightDarkActionBar);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);

    setContentView(mViewPager);

    ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);

    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Tab1"), Tab1.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Tab2"),
            Tab2.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Tab3"), Tab3.class,
            null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Tab4"), Tab4.class, null);


}

public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
        ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private final Context mContext;
    private final ActionBar mActionBar;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

    static final class TabInfo {
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;

        TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }

    public TabsAdapter(SherlockFragmentActivity activity, ViewPager pager) {
        super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        mContext = activity;
        mActionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
        mViewPager = pager;
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
        tab.setTag(info);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        mTabs.add(info);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTabs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(),
                info.args);
    }

    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
            int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
    }

    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Object tag = tab.getTag();
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabs.size(); i++) {
            if (mTabs.get(i) == tag) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}
```

How can I make it work?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this at the end of your `onCreate` method:

```
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
```

The [above method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem%28int%29) should be 0-based, so 1 is the second page.

Comment: Thanks a LOT! It worked. I had already tried but I was putting it before adding the tabs. putting after adding the tabs did it. Thanks again.